# Floating point calculation with constants in C?

Tags: c, constants

I can use float calculation with constants within my C compiler!

For example

```
 if ( a > (100/0.1) )
```

will compare a with 1000

And doing

```
#define PARAMETER  777
#define FACTOR (1/3.1415)
int a = PARAMETER/FACTOR
```

will set a to 2440, which is the integer part of floating point result 2440.9455

Is this a standard behaviour of C compilers, that I can calculate with floating point constants or ist this behavoir compiler dependent?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you surprised that you can do floating point math in C, or that you can specify floating point numbers directly in code, or...?

Comment: `that I can calculate with floating point constants` - did you expect that you can do floating point calculations only with variables?

Comment: what you are doing is `type casting` in c, when you declare `a`. It is the standard behaviour in C.

Comment: It's standard. In general, the compiler will reduce the the constant expressions at compile time. (I.e. it will produce executable code that initializes variable `a`  with the constant 2440 directly, rather than producing executable code that does the floating point calculation, converts it to `int`, and initializes variable `a` with the result.)

Comment: Thaks! It's good to know that this behavoir is standard.

Comment: "will compare a with 1000" actually it will compare with `1000.0` as the result of the division is of type `double`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can perform floating-point arithmetic with constants in expressions in C programs, and yes, the compiler will often reduce these expressions at compile time.  The situation is almost the same as for integer constants.  That is, your example

```
if(a > (100 / 0.1))
```

is just as legal as the integer example

```
if(a > (100 * 10))
```

There remain two things to worry about:

1. Especially on older compilers, the floating-point model used during compilation may be different, and may give you slightly different answers, than the model used at run time.
2. The innocent-looking decimal fraction `0.1` can, famously, *no*t be represented exactly in binary floating point, so your expression `100 / 0.1` might reduce to something like 999.99999 or 1000.00001.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( a > (100/0.1) )
```

This will reduce to `if (a > 1000.0)` Here before the comparison, `a` is converted to a double and compared with `1000.0`. This is generally safe as long as you do not have too large numbers. For very big numbers the conversion of `a` might result in an error of 1.

```
int a = PARAMETER/FACTOR
```

This will reduce to `int a = 777/(1/3.1415)` i.e. `int a = 2440.9455`

In this case, you the float `2440.9455` will be typecast to an `int` which is how you get 2440.

Comment: In common C implementations, `777/(1/3.1415)` yields 2440.945499999999810825102031230926513671875, not 2440.9455.